# Muting the LLVM IR debug output when using Numba?

Tags: python, anaconda, numba

I am wanting to use Numba in one of our in-house client libraries, however there's a debug dump of the LLVM IR code every time my code JITs something.   Is there a setting in Numba or in LLVM that I can change so as to mute this stuff: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDm9D.png ?

Thank you.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112584/huge-errors-trying-numba/19113501?noredirect=1#comment28261812_19113501).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was corrected in the numba code on github.  someone left a debug flag set to True.

Comment: it's corrected in github, but the stable release is still 0.11 which does not contain the fix.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay with the release version of numba 0.11, and you can't control the python optimization level, this will work (just tried it myself):

```
import logging

def disableNumbaLogging():
    import numba.codegen.debug

    llvmlogger = logging.getLogger('numba.codegen.debug')
    llvmlogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking `python -O`. This way, basic optimizations will be enabled and IR dump will be silenced.