# Prevent Numba from printing @autojit functions to standard output?

Tags: python, numba

I have a five nested for loop function (convolution of images by 3d filters) that I desperately needed to speed up and used numba's @autojit decorator for it quite happily. The only complaint I have is when the function is called the first time, numba does its autojit but prints what I think is the internal representation of the jitted function to standard out which can take several seconds to scroll by, i.e. stuff like this:

```
empty1:                                           ; preds = %empty
  %16 = call i32 inttoptr (i64 139980888423164 to i32 ({ i64, i8* }*)*)({ i64, i8* }* %10)
  br label %empty3

empty2:                                           ; preds = %empty
  br label %error_label

empty3:                                           ; preds = %empty1
  %17 = call i8* @PyErr_Occurred()
  %18 = ptrtoint i8* %17 to i64
  %19 = icmp ne i64 %18, 0
  br i1 %19, label %empty5, label %empty4

empty4:                                           ; preds = %empty3
  %20 = call { i64, i8* }* @__numba_specialized_2___main___2E_max_pool({ i64, i8*, i8*, i32, i64*, i64*, i8*, i8*, i32, i8* }* %11, i32 %12, i32 %16)
  store { i64, i8* }* %20, { i64, i8* }** %objtemp, !tbaa !6
  %21 = ptrtoint { i64, i8* }* %20 to i64
  %22 = icmp eq i64 %21, 0
  br i1 %22, label %error_label, label %no_error

empty5:                                           ; preds = %empty3
  br label %error_label

no_error:                                         ; preds = %empty4
  %23 = load { i64, i8* }** %objtemp, !tbaa !6
  store { i64, i8* }* %23, { i64, i8* }** %return_value
  %24 = load { i64, i8* }** %return_value, !tbaa !6
  call void @Py_XINCREF({ i64, i8* }* %24)
  br label %cleanup_label
}

!tbaa = !{!0, !1, !2, !3, !4, !5, !6, !7, !8, !9, !10, !11, !12, !13, !14, !15, !16, !17, !18, !19, !20, !21, !22, !23, !0, !1, !6, !0, !1, !2, !3, !4, !5, !6, !24, !12, !7, !13, !14, !15, !16, !17, !25, !0, !1, !6}
```

Does anyone know how to disable this? It works fine, it's fast, and it doesn't throw errors, but it's a bit annoying.

Comment: Is this the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116374/muting-the-llvm-ir-debug-output-when-using-numba)?

Comment: Yep it is! Apologies, didn't show up from some searching and googling.